# How can I add proper typing to a reduce over functions?

Tags: typescript

Below I have a function called `j`, its purpose is to take an `object` where its values are `functions` and resolve each object `property` in series (reducing), and assign the returned value of the function to its corresponding key.

The function itself is pretty straight forward, a `_.reduce`, that also resolves promise values, allowing for the value-functions to be `async`, and spreading the result over the accumulated object.

Each function has access to the passed in arguments as well as each previous functions keyed-return value.

I am looking to type this function `j` so that there is sensible typing on the function that `j` returns. In the case of the example below the `customAnimal` function takes an `animal` prop, and there is no `animal` key in the object, so it is clear that the value must be an input into the function that `j` returns.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

export const isPromise = (obj) => !!obj && (typeof obj === 'object' || typeof obj === 'function') && typeof obj.then === 'function'

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type Jin = { [key: string]: Function }

const j = (objFns: Jin): Function => {
  /** Parameters<> object where combind all parameters from all object values */
  /** ReturnType<> all object keys with types as return types from functions, merged with original args */
  return (input) => {
    return _.reduce(_.toPairs(objFns), (acq, pair) => {
      const [key, fn] = pair
      const handleResult = (acq, result) => {
        const addition = { [key]: result}
        return { ...acq, ...addition }
      }
      const handleResultPossiblePromise = (acq, result) => {
        const resultIsPromise = isPromise(result)
        if (resultIsPromise) return result.then(result => handleResult(acq, result))
        return handleResult(acq, result)
      }
      const handleAcqPossiblePromise = (acq) => {
        const acqIsPromise = isPromise(acq)
        if (acqIsPromise) return acq.then(acq => handleResultPossiblePromise(acq, fn(acq)))
        return handleResultPossiblePromise(acq, fn(acq))
      }
      return handleAcqPossiblePromise(acq)
    }, input)
  }
}
```

```
const makePoem = j({
  color: () => 'blue',
  sky: ({ color }) => `the color of the sky is ${color}`,
  ocean: ({ color }) => `the color of the ocean is ${color}`,
  customAnimal: ({ animal, color }) => `the color of the ${animal} is ${color}`,
  poem: ({ sky, ocean, customAnimal }) => [sky, ocean, customAnimal].join('\n'),
})

console.log(makePoem({ animal: 'cat' }))
```

It seems that typing a function like this is very complex, but perhaps it is not. Are there any generics that can `Merge<>` together all the `Parameters<>` from each function, and perhaps Diff with the arguments provided? When declaring `j` is there a way to define what `j` needs? Something similar to how styled-components does `withProps<IProps, HTMLDivElement>(styled.div)`?

How can I type `j` so that the function `makePoem` is typed properly?

Comment: Is your question dependent on lodash?  If so, please tag it as such.  If not, please remove the example code's dependency on it.  Good luck!